# Cocos2D-X for IOS App but on a windows machine

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cocos2d-x

I have bought a Mac Mini because I'd like to develop IOS game but I really don't like OS X, XCode, Mac Tactile Mouse, Mac Keyboard (sorry for the apple fans here). Apple make really great mobile device, but I really don't appreciate their computer.. So what I'd like to do is to use Cocos2d-X to develop under Visual Studio in C++ (moreover I need to develop a Level Editor) and then only use the Mac to test the app on my iPad and maybe deploy it one day :)

So I'd like to know if there is a good tutorial around to know how to well organize my project under windows, cause I don't want to have too much extra work when passing it to XCode to test it.

At the moment I have setup my Cocos2D-X project under VS but I feel like I will be in trouble about resources and dependencies when I will try to take it to XCode...

Is anyone working with that workflow ? Have you advice ?

Thank a lot.

Comment: swap the mac's mouse & keyboard with your favorites (MS Natural 4000 here), change the keyboard layout, and get used to the rest. It's easier to adapt yourself than (fight) technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cocos2d-XNA with Visual Studio and Xamarin.iOS.

So you will be able to use Visual Studio to write iOS Games.

http://xamarin.com/visual-studio